# ObjectiveC blocks Java equivalent

Tags: java, objective-c-blocks

There's a feature of the Apple Objective-C language which is really useful to me: I can pass code blocks as argument in methods.

I'd like to do that in Java, too.
Something like:

```
myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(function() {
   dao.save();  
});
```

So the myManager object will execute my code between a startTransaction() and a endTransaction() methods.

Is there a way to get that in Java?

Comment: The simple answer is "no", there's no functionality like that in Java.

Comment: For 2014, the answer seems to be "just use a Runnable".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't support this. But you can get similar functionality with anonymous classes.

To do so, first you define an interface:

```
interface TransactionAction {
    public void perform();
}
```

`doSomethingInTransaction` should then be defined to take a `TransactionAction` as an argument.

Then, when you call it, do this:

```
myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(new TransactionAction() {
    public void perform() {
        dao.save();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

No this does not exist in Java (yet). A workaround is to use the `Runnable` interface:

```
myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dao.save();  
    }
});
```

or any interface with a single method will do.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 4):

you can use an Interface like

```
interface CodeBlock {
    void execute();
}
```

the function would look like

```
someType functionToBeExecuted(CodeBlock cb) {
    ...
}
```

it would be called like

```
functionToBeExecuted(new CodeBlock() {
   void execute() {
       // blah
   }
});
```

But if your code should be able to access variables or fields in will be more specialized. Also performance will be lower this way because of the new objects.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible in Java 8 using a lambda expression:

```
myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(() -> {
    dao.save();  
});
```

Or more tersely:

```
myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(() -> dao.save());
```

Your implementation of `doSomethingInTransaction` should accept a `Runnable` parameter, or any other single-method interface with a matching method signature.

You can find Oracle's documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: This could even be simplified to `myManager.doSomethingInTransaction(dao::save);`

Comment: Ho can I make a reference to lambda?